# Function in Global Environment faster than package in R

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, package

I created the 'starvars' package stored on  github (https://github.com/andbucci/starvars) and on the CRAN to estimate and predict a Vector Logistic Autoregressive Model.

Something that I cannot understand happens with the following example:

```
set.seed(261088)

####Loading data####

data("techprices", package = "starvars")

####Deriving realized covariances from stock prices####
RCOV <- rcov(techprices, freq = "monthly", make.ret = TRUE, cholesky = TRUE)
techchol <- RCOV$'Cholesky Factors' ##Cholesky factors of realized covariance matrices

####Testing for nonlinearity in the multivariate time series####
st <- lag(techchol,1)[-1,]

##Searching starting values for c and gamma
stvalues <- startingVLSTAR(techchol[-1,], p = 1, m = 2, st = st[,5], n.combi = 20, ncores = 4)

####Estimating a VLSTAR model####
fit.VLSTAR <- VLSTAR(techchol[-1,], p = 1, m = 2, st = st[,5], starting = stvalues,
                     method = 'NLS', n.iter = 30, ncores = 4)
```

The `VLSTAR` function (the updated version on github) takes 15 minutes to run the example if called directly from the package, while it takes 2 minutes if called from the Global Environment. Can anybody explain this? In such case, how can I improve the in-package behaviour of the function?

Comment: What do you mean "if called directly from the package"?  Show us what you did to get the difference in timing.  You used the "parallel-processing" tag, suggesting some of your functions use parallel processing.  A guess is that the distribution of work to processes is different in the two cases, so a suggestion would be to print information about that when you run.

Comment: I mean that by installing the package and running the function from the package the estimation takes 15 min, while the same function when used directly from the global environment takes 2 min. I had the same thought about parallel computation that is indeed used in the optimization of an objective function. Task Manager shows me that in one case (from global environment) all the processes are executed within RStudio, in the other it seems that the two processes are executed within RStudio and the other two are executed outside it. How can I print the information about parallel computation?

Comment: Two comments. 1. If you enter a function at the console, its environment is the global environment, while a function in a package uses the package namespace.  So the two versions look in different places for the calls they make, and that might be why you're seeing different timings: they're running different functions.  2.  There are several different ways to request parallel processes.  I'm not familiar with any of them, but I'd expect they have different ways to get info about what has been scheduled and executed.

Comment: Is there a way to force the import of the function in the global environment? Is it a viable solution or is it too naive?

Comment: It is almost certainly a bad idea, but you can change the environment of `pkg::fun` using `fun <- pkg::fun; environment(fun) <- globalenv()`.  But don't expect it to work after you do that.

Comment: I think that the issue is related to the memory usage of the function that is different within and outside the package. I am not an expert in R package, but I imagine this is related to the functions loaded through the namespace. Is there a way to improve that in my package? In the namespace, I am actually importing from the packages only the functions that I use.

Comment: I think that's very unlikely to be true.  You are using different functions, that's all.

Comment: What do you mean by different functions? Are you referring to the functions from external packages?

Comment: No, I was just repeating what I said earlier.  The main difference between functions entered at the console and functions in packages is where they look for the functions they use.  They look in different places, so they often execute different functions.  That's almost certainly why you're seeing different timings:  the functions are doing different things.  Since you haven't shown us any reproducible version of your question, I'm voting to close it.